# componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet issue

Tags: objective-c

I have a string named "result" as I need to obtain the numbers from a mathematical expression.The expression is given as an NSString. I use the method `[NSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:]` method that gives an NSArray containing the components.But I get few doubts.Here is the code.

```
NSString *result=[obj computeTheExp:@"+19+55/23-42*3-34-"];
```

I use this method on it

```
NSArray *operands = [inputString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-/*"]];
```

When I display contents of operands using

```
NSLog(@"%i",[operands count]);

    for(i=0;i<[operands count];i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[operands objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
```

I get this on console

```
2013-08-05 16:47:52.967 mathExpTest[6708] 8
2013-08-05 16:47:52.992 mathExpTest[6708]
2013-08-05 16:47:53.002 mathExpTest[6708] 19
2013-08-05 16:47:53.012 mathExpTest[6708] 55
2013-08-05 16:47:53.022 mathExpTest[6708] 23
2013-08-05 16:47:53.032 mathExpTest[6708] 42
2013-08-05 16:47:53.042 mathExpTest[6708] 3
2013-08-05 16:47:53.052 mathExpTest[6708] 34
2013-08-05 16:47:53.062 mathExpTest[6708]
```

Shouldn't the count be 6?And why are there gaps in the display?

Comment: As is it null before your component + and after last -, so it is showing you like this. Where z d confusion now?

Comment: Your question was a useful example of how this method works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is normal. From documentation: "if the string begins or ends with separator characters, the first or last substring, respectively, is empty" http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html -

Answer (score 4):

Your string starts and ends with separator characters, this is the reason. This is the defined response of `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` in this situation:

> Adjacent occurrences of the separator characters produce empty strings in the result. Similarly, if the string begins or ends with separator characters, the first or last substring, respectively, is empty.

Comment: I understood the problem.Thanks a ton.How can I get rid of those nulls?

Comment: You can trim the first and last characters if they are in your set of operands. That can be done using `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`.

Comment: Great, please mark answers as correct if they solved the problem.